# Evaluate variable in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have arrays named :

```
test_1
test_2
```

And I have a variable that can hold either `1` or `2`. ie. `id`, in case id has value `1` how can I add something to that array in this case do :

```
test_#{id} << "value" #-> Where id is 1
```

it should be executed like :

```
test_1 << "value"
```

Update :

test_1 and test_2 are local variables.

```
test_1 = []
test_2 = []

id = 1
```

how to do this :

test_id where id is value of id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With local variables, you can do it like this:

```
test_1 = []
test_2 = []
eval("test_#{id}") << "value"
```

You can do it slightly better with instance variables:

```
@test_1 = []
@test_2 = []
instance_variable_get("@test_#{id}") << "value"
```

But a better way to handle this case is to use a hash with the `id` as the key:

```
test = {1 => [], 2 => []}
test[id] << "value"
```

Comment: Assuming the indexes are dense, an array could also work instead of the hash. I'm always a bit wary to use integer keys in hashes...

Comment: @HolgerJust Array will make it complicated in this case because there is no entry with the index `0`.

Comment: `test[id-1]` to the rescue :) Or you could just make the indexes zero-based.

Comment: @HolgerJust That is the complexity I am talking about.

Comment: I'm just presenting alternatives. But let's just agree that all these variants work and are rather similar in complexity in this tiny toy example we have here. If things get more complex it's up to the OP to decide which one to use.

Answer (score 3):

For these cases you should use `Hash` instead.

```
results = {}
results['test_1'] = []
results['test_2'] = []

# If we sure that id is in [1,2]. Otherwise we need add check here, or change `results` definition to allow unexisting cases. 
results["test_#{id}"] << 'value'
```

Comment: While the answer by @sawa works, this one is cleaner as it involves less magic and better encapsulates the data.